# Does DocumentDB support mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

I am using AWS document db v4.0.0. It works fine with my application using MongoDB driver to connect. But when I try to use mongo shell it gives me some errors on basic query:

```
db.myCollection.find({})
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 303,
    "errmsg" : "Feature not supported: 'causal consistency'",
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1645150705, 1)
}
```

Does this mean DocumentDB is not compatible with mongo shell?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the actual connection part, but make sure you have the TLS keys placed on the machine.

Your connection string should be something like this:

```
mongo --ssl host docdb-2020-02-08-14-15-11. cluster.region.docdb.amazonaws.com:27107 --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username demoUser --password
```

There is actually a really good example/explanation in the official [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-ec2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Casual consistency isn't supported in DocumentDB. From your mongo shell you can run "db.getMongo().setCausalConsistency(false)" then re-run your find operation.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Mongo.setCausalConsistency/